# Calculate mean and variance of a distribution

Tags: probability

So I have a continuous distribution with CDF $F(x) = 1 - \exp((-x^2)/2), x>0$.

For the mean, I got the derivative $f(x) = x\exp((-x^2)/2)$, but the integral for $E(X)$ gives me $-\sqrt{2\pi}/2$, which must not be right, since the CDF is only defined for $x>0$.

Also, any tips on how to calculate the variance, because I feel the formula $E(X^2) - \mu^2$ will lead me to similarly strange results. Is this the CDF of a known distribution that I am missing?

Comment: I believe this is a [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution). You should double check your expectation computation.

Comment: @angryavian Weibull might very well be known, but it isn't known to me yet :p Also, yes, I messed up 1 minus sign in my computation

Answer (score 1):

Note that $X> 0$ with probability one. Then we can use the fact that in this case
$$
EX=\int_0^\infty 1-F(x)\, dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2/2}\, dx=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}.
$$
Next
$$
EX^2=\int_0^\infty2x(1-F(x))=\int_0^\infty 2x(e^{-x^2/2})\, dx=\int_0^\infty e^{-u/2}\, du=2.
$$

Comment: I actually found the mistake in my computation for the mean, and I got the correct result. For the variance, how did you derive this formula? Is it standard? Because i only knew the formula with the integral of $((x - μ)^2)f(x)$

Comment: @JBuck See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1415376)