# Compute the expected value of a random variable $Y$ that has a distribution function defined by parts

Tags: random-variables, expected-value

Let $X$ be a nonnegative random variable with continuous distribution $F$. And let $Y$ be a random variable with CDF
\begin{equation}
G(y) = 
\begin{cases}
1- \alpha\int_{y}^{\infty}(1- F(x) )dx, &y>0 \\
0,  &y \leq 0,
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $\alpha = \frac{1}{E(X)}$.

Here is my attempt:

$$
E(Y) =\int_{0}^{\infty} [1-G(y)]dy = \int_{0}^{\infty} [1-\{ 1-\alpha \int_{y}^{\infty}(1- F(x)) dx \} ]dy = \alpha \int_{0}^{\infty}  \int_{y}^{\infty}(1- F(x) )dxdy.
$$

But at this point I'm stuck, I do not know how to proceed. Do you know how compute $E(Y)$ using this formula? or Do you know other way to compute $E(Y)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By interchanging the order of integration, your last integral becomes
$$\int_0^\infty (1-F(x))\int_0^x \, dy \, dx = \int_0^\infty x(1-F(x)) \, dx = \frac{1}{2} E[X^2]$$
where the last equality is [shown here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415366/variance-formula-in-terms-of-the-cdf-for-a-continuous-nonnegative-random-variabl).

Comment: thank you, It took me a moment but now I understand your answer.