# Prove that $E(Y)-E(X)= \int_\Bbb{R}\Bbb{P}(X<t\leq Y)-\Bbb{P}(Y<t\leq X)\, dt$

Tags: probability, expected-value

> **Problem.** Let $\left(\Omega, \mathcal A, \Bbb{P} \right)$ be a probability space and $X,Y$ be real-valued random variables with finite expected value. Then $$E(Y)-E(X)= \int_\Bbb{R}\Bbb{P}(X<t\leq Y)-\Bbb{P}(Y<t\leq X)\, dt.$$

**My attempt.** This isn't much of an attempt, but I've written
$$\int_\Bbb{R}\Bbb{P}(X<t\leq Y)-\Bbb{P}(Y<t\leq X)\, dt = \int_\Bbb{R} E\left(\mathbf 1\{X<t\leq Y\}-\mathbf 1\{Y<t\leq X\} \right) dt$$
Can we interchange integration and $E$? How could we proceed?

Comment: Even though this post is slightly different, I’d like to link it to the current choice of [mother post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841). Also see the meta post for [(abstract) duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29382/356647).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we interchange integration with expectation using Fubini-Tonelli. (This uses the finite expected value condition.)
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}E({\bf 1}\{X<t\leq Y\}-{\bf 1}\{Y<t\leq X\})=E\left(\int_{\mathbb R}{\bf 1}\{X<t\leq Y\}-{\bf 1}\{Y<t\leq X\}\right)=E(Y-X).
$$
The last step follows from the the deterministic identity
$$
Y-X=\int_{\mathbb R}{\bf 1}\{X<t\leq Y\}-{\bf 1}\{Y<t\leq X\}
$$
for any real numbers $X,Y\in \mathbb R$ (just consider each of the two cases $X\leq Y$ and  $X\geq Y$ separately).

Comment: why Tonelli? is everything is positive here?

Comment: Well, the standard way is to split $f$ into positive and negative parts and to apply Tonelli to each separately.