# $\int_{\mathbb R+} P(Y-X>t)dt$ =$\int_{\mathbb R}P(X < y, Y >y)dy$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

i have  $E[B]= \int_{\mathbb R+} P(Y-X>t)dt$
and i want to show this relation :
 $\int_{\mathbb R+} P(Y-X>t)dt$=$\int_{\mathbb R}P(X < y, Y >y)dy$

I first began showing that for t ≥ 0, $ P(Y − X>t) = \int_{\mathbb R^2} 1_{y>x+t}f_{X|Y=y} (x) f_y(y)  dxdy$

But i don't know how to continue

Comment: Even though there's already an accepted answer, I'd still like to link a closely related [old post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1427801).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_{\mathbb R} P(X<y,Y>y)dy=\int_{\mathbb R}\int I_{\{X<y<Y\}} dPdy=\int_{\mathbb R}\int I_{\{X<y<Y\}} dydP=\int (Y-X)^{+} dP$ and $\int (Y-X)^{+} dP=\int_0^{\infty} P(Y-X>t)dt$. I have used Fubini's Theorem and the fact that $Z=\int_0^{\infty} P(Z>t)\, dt$ for any non-negative random variable $Z$. Take $Z=(X-Y)^{+}$.

Comment: thank you can you just specify what is the measure when you integrate with respect to dP

Comment: The random variables are defined on some probability space and $P$ is the probability measure on that space.

Comment: but this is two random variable that's the thing who stuck me what is the boundary of the second integral and what is the the space ?

Comment: Are you familiar with probability spaces and random variables on them? You are using density functions in your argument but not every random variable has  a density. My integrals are over the sample space $\Omega$.

Comment: thank you finally i get it