# Expected value & Lebesgue integral

Tags: probability, lebesgue-integral

Let $\langle \Omega, \mathcal{F}, P \rangle$ be a probability triple, $X \, : \, \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ be a random variable (assume it takes only non-negative values for simplicity). In general, we can define expected value as a Lebesgue integral (“L” for Lebesgue, “RS” for Riemann–Stieltjes):

$E[X] \equiv (L) \int_{\Omega} X(\omega) \, dP \stackrel{?}{=} (RS) \int_{X(\Omega)} x \, dF(x)$.

How do we actually prove the last step?

We have our function $X(\omega)$ and our measure $P$, so thinking about Lebesgue integral is pretty natural. [We can rewrite it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration#Towards_a_formal_definition):

$(L) \int_{\Omega} X(\omega) \, dP = (R) \int_{0}^{\infty} P \{ \omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) > t\} \, dt$,

and the integrand here seems to have something to do with CDF.

**UPD**: $E[X] < \infty$,

$\int_{0}^{\infty} P \{ \omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) > t\} \, dt =
\int_{0}^{\infty} (1 - F(t)) \, dt =
\lim_{u \to \infty} [(1 - F(u))u + \int_{0}^{u} x \, dF(x)]$.

Feels like it’s almost done. How can we show that the first term tends to zero ($0 \cdot \infty$)?

Comment: The right hand-side is $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty (1-F(t))\,dt$ which is indeed $E[X]$ if $X$ is a non-negative random variable and $F(t)$ is its cumulative distribution function..  See for example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841/integral-of-cdf-equals-expected-value and the other questions linked to it

Comment: Thanks, I came up w/ the idea to integrate it by parts. Yet it’s not enough.