# Complimentary Cumulative Distribution Function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a nonnegative r.v. with cdf $F$ and $E[X]<\infty$.  Consider the indicator function.  Show that

$$E[X] = \int_{0}^{\infty} F^c(x) dx$$
where $F^c(x) := 1 - F(x)$.

There is a hint provided that says: First claim that $\int_{0}^{\infty} 1_{{X>x}} dx = X$.
Use that result to show that 
$$E[X^m] = m \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{m-1}F^c(x)dx, m \geq 1$$

Comment: Despite being already closed, this comment is to link this post as one of the [(abstract) duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29382/356647) to the current choice of [mother post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841).

Answer (score 2):

First, note that the result of the hint with $m=1$ proves the original question, so we just need to show this more general result.

So,
\begin{align*}
m\int_0^\infty x^{m-1} F^c(x) \mathop{dx}
&= m \int_0^\infty x^{m-1} E[\mathbf{1}_{X>x}]\mathop{dx}
\\
&= E\left[m \int_0^\infty x^{m-1} \mathbf{1}_{X>x} \mathop{dx}\right] & \text{Fubini (switch expectation and integration)}
\\
&= E\left[\int_0^X mx^{m-1} \mathop{dx}\right]
\\
&= E[X^m].
\end{align*}