# If $X$ has finite expectation then $\int_M^\infty (1-F(x))\,dx \rightarrow 0 $ as $M\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Assume that we have a random variable $X$ that has a CDF $F$ (can be assumed to be continuous if required), and finite expectation, $\mathbb{E}(X) < \infty$. Then, does 
$$
\int_M^\infty (1-F(x))\,dx \rightarrow 0  
$$
as $M\rightarrow\infty$?

This seems to be trivially clear (otherwise, the probability of $X$ exceeding $M$ would not go to 0), but I don't know how to show this formally. As the expectation is finite, the integral $\int_0^\infty (1-F(x))\,dx$ should be finite, but I am not sure if that really helps.

Comment: Yes; this follows from $x\mapsto 1-F(x)$ being monotone decreasing on $(0,\infty)$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-F(x))=0$.

Comment: Should the limit read $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}$?

Comment: Much simpler still: For every nonnegative function $G$ such that $\int_0^\infty G$ converges, one knows that $\int_M^\infty G\to0$ when $M\to\infty$ (this is almost the *definition* of the convergence of the integral). And you know that $\int_0^\infty(1-F)$ converges since you assumed that $E(X)$ is finite and, for every nonnegative $X$, [$E(X)=\int_0^\infty (1-F)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/172857/6179).

Comment: @Did Indeed, thanks. X is, however, not non-negative, but the argument should still hold as that integral should still be finite, right?

Comment: @user3825755 Yes, although you could also write the limit as $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-F_(x_n))$ for an increasing sequence $\{x_n\}$ with $\sup_n x_n=+\infty$.

Comment: For $X$ real valued, check the convergence using $\int_0^\infty(1-F)=E(\max(X,0))\leqslant E(|X|)$.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I see. I realized that one can also write the integral as $\int \mathbb{P}(X \geq x) dx = \mathbb{E}(X - M)I(X \geq M)$, where $I$ denotes the indicator function, which converges to 0 by the finiteness of the expectation of $X$.

Comment: Yes, same argument. Well done. Post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following from some comments to the question, note that the integral is equal to $\int_M^\infty\mathbb{P}(X\geq x)dx = \mathbb{E}((X-M)I(X\geq M))$ where $I$ denotes the indicator function. The last expression converges to $0$ by the assumed finiteness of the integral. Hence the result holds.