# Expected value of a function in terms of CDF

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, probability-distributions, expectation

Is there any formula for computing the expected value E(f(X)) using the cumulated distribution function (CDF), rather than the probability density function (PDF)?

Comment: Check this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841/integral-of-cdf-equals-expected-value

Comment: If  $P(X\geqslant0)=1$, then $$E(f(X))=f(0)+\int_0^\infty f'(x)(1-F_X(x))dx$$

Comment: thank you for the answer. what about P(X⩾0)<1, this is too restricting

Comment: $$E(f(X))=f(0)+\int_0^{+\infty}f'(x)(1-F_X(x))dx-\int_{-\infty}^0f'(x)F_X(x)dx$$