# Maximize functional over weakly decreasing $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, calculus-of-variations

> Find the maximum value of
>
> $$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \left| f(x) - f^{-1}(y) \right|^{3} \,\mathrm d x \,\mathrm d y$$
>
> over weakly decreasing functions $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$, where $$f^{-1}(y) := \inf\left\{x : f(x) \le y \right\}$$

I am trying  to find out how one should proceed with such a problem. I will welcome any partial solution, ideas or good tips. I even wonder if solving this problem is fairly easy or terribly complicated task.

Comment: This question can be stated also as: maximize over random variables $X$ taking values in $[0,1]$  the following: $\int_{0}^{1} \mathbb{E} |X-\mathbb{P}(X\ge u)|^3 du.$ Maybe this might be of some use.

Comment: It is somehow similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2209895/617199.

Comment: I would also welcome any not-trivial upper bound.