# Expectetion of $Y^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha >0$

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $Y$ be a positive random variable.  For $\alpha>0$ show that

$E(Y^{\alpha})=\alpha \int_{0}^{\infty}t^{\alpha -1}P(Y>t)dt$.

My ideas:

$E(Y^{\alpha})= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}t^{\alpha}f_{Y}(t)dt$

=$\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{\alpha}f_{Y}(t)dt$

=$\int_{0}^{\infty}(\int_{0}^{t^{\alpha}}dy)f_{Y}(t)dt$

Comment: Do you know that $Y$ is continuous?

Comment: Yes, $Y$ is continuous.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841/explain-why-ex-int-0-infty-1-f-x-t-dt-for-every-nonnegative-rando

Comment: It's not obvious from the title: an answer to the post [172841](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841) that Alex Pozo linked to deals with exactly this question. Another choice is [2289899](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2289899), which is itself closed as a duplicate to #172841.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E(Y^\alpha)=\int_0^\infty t^\alpha f_y(t)dt$.  Let $G_y(t)=P(Y\gt t)=1-F_y(t)$.  Therefore $G'_y(t)=-f_y(t)$.   Integrate $E(Y^\alpha)$ by parts and get $E(Y^\alpha)=-t^\alpha G_y(t)\rbrack_0^\infty +\alpha \int_0^\infty t^{\alpha-1}G_y(t)dt={\alpha \int_0^\infty t^{\alpha-1}P(Y\gt t)dt}$.

Answer (score 1):

By Tonelli's theorem (i.e. switching the order of integration),
\begin{align*}
\int_{[0,\infty)}\alpha t^{\alpha-1}P[Y>t]\,dt &= \int_{[0,\infty)}\alpha t^{\alpha-1}\int_\Omega 1_{\{\omega':Y(\omega')>t\}}(\omega)\,P(d\omega)\,dt \\
&= \int_\Omega\int_{[0,\infty)} \alpha t^{\alpha-1}1_{\{\omega':Y(\omega')>t\}}(\omega)\,dt\,P(d\omega) \\
&= \int_\Omega\int_{[0,Y(\omega))}\alpha t^{\alpha-1}\,dt\,P(d\omega) \\
&= \int_\Omega Y(\omega)^\alpha\,P(d\omega) \qquad\text{fundamental theorem of calculus} \\
&= E(Y^\alpha),
\end{align*}
as desired. This method also does not require that the distribution function be continuous, merely integrable.

Comment: I don't understand the $3_{rd}$ '=' sign. Could you explain that to me?

Comment: @Jasper: In the integral $\int_{[0,\infty)}\alpha t^{\alpha-1}1_{\{\omega':Y(\omega')>t\}}(\omega)\,dt$, $\omega$ is fixed, so if $t\ge Y(\omega)$, then $1_{\{\omega':Y(\omega')>t\}}(\omega) = 0$. Hence we only integrate over those $t$ such that $0 \le t < Y(\omega)$, i.e., where $1_{\{\omega':Y(\omega')>t\}}(\omega) = 1$. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ahh yes, thank you!