# Expected Value with certain probability in absolute value

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable and $M$ a constant such that $P[\lvert X\rvert\leq M]=1$.
Show that $\lvert E(X) \rvert\leq E(\lvert X \rvert)\leq M$

For the first part, let $g(X)=\lvert X \rvert$ then $g$ is a convex function and then, by jensen inequality
\begin{equation}
g(E(X))\leq E(g(x)) \Rightarrow \lvert E(X) \rvert\leq E(\lvert X \rvert)
\end{equation}
How do I prove the second inequality? thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have, writing a tautology and using a crude bound,
$$
|X| = |X|\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\leq M\}} + |X|\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|> M\}} \leq 
M\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\leq M\}} + |X|\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|> M\}} \tag{1}
$$
so that, by linearity of expectation,
$$
\mathbb{E}[|X|] \leq  \mathbb{E}[M\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\leq M\}}]
+ \mathbb{E}[|X|\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|> M\}}]
= M\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\leq M\}}]
+ \mathbb{E}[|X|\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|> M\}}] \tag{2}
$$
Finally,
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\leq M\}}] = \mathbb{P}\{|X|\leq M\} = 1
$$
while
$
\mathbb{E}[\lvert X\rvert\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|> M\}}] = 0$ since $\mathbb{P}\{|X|> M\}=0$.

Answer (score 2):

For [non-negative random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841/explain-why-ex-int-0-infty-1-f-x-t-dt-for-every-nonnegative-rando?noredirect=1&lq=1), $X$,

$$ E[X] = \int_0^\infty P(X > x)dx $$

Since $|X| \leq M$ almost surely, $\{|X| > x\} \subseteq \{M > x\}$. Thus,

$$ E[|X|] = \int_0^\infty P(|X| > x)dx \leq \int_0^\infty P(M > x)dx = \int_0^\infty \chi_{\{M > x\}}dx = M$$

Comment: I must assumed $X$ is non negative

Comment: No, because $|X|$ is.

Comment: True, did not see that, but how do I prove your second line? i can't see it clearly

Comment: @Karen it is a classic trick, useful to know: $$\int_{0}^\infty x P(X \in dx) = \int_{0}^\infty \int_0^x dy P(X \in dx) = \int_0^\infty dy \int_{x}^\infty P(X \in dx) = \int_0^\infty P(X>y)dy$$