# Changing expectations into probability.

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

Going through a proof (related to probability) I found on a paper(Comp sci.)  i could not undertstand the steps he followed. Basically the author did the following steps:

$$E(T_{Fail}) = E(t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}} - t_{k} | t_{k} < t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}} \le t_{k + 1})$$

$$E(T_{Fail}) = \int^{t_{k+1} - t_{k}}_{0} P(\tau > t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}} 
 - {t}_{k} | t_{k} < t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}} \le  t_{k + 1}) d \tau$$

$\tau$ is not defined anywhere throughout the paper.

There are more steps after the above-mentioned lines(too much to type).

So i don't know how we are moving from expectation to probability. The link to the paper is: http://nslab.kaist.ac.kr/courses/2014/cs712/paperlist/2-17.pdf

Page:19 and 20.
Thank you.

Comment: The first rule of MathJax is not to end your MathJax environment in the middle of a formula. Absolutely do not try to use HTML tags such as `<sub>` to format things inside the formula; it makes things far, far more difficult. Can you see how much easier it is when you use the tool the way it was designed?

Answer (score 1):

> $\tau$ is not defined anywhere throughout the paper.

Not true. It's defined right here:

$$\int_0^{t_{k+1} - t_k} P(\tau > t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}} 
 - t_k \mid t_k < t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}} \le  t_{k + 1})\, d \tau. \tag1$$

The notation $d\tau$ inside an integral like this tells you that $\tau$ is the variable over which the integral is integrated.
That's all it is, and this definition applies only inside the integral.

---

I believe there *is* an error in the paper. It is possible that it is canceled out by another error, but the following is as far as I have gotten at this time:

It is a fact (which the authors of the paper assume the reader will know)
that if $X$ is a non-negative random variable with a finite expectation, then
$$ E(X) = \int_0^\infty P(X>\tau)\, d\tau. \tag2$$
Refer to the answers to [Explain why $E(X) = \int_0^\infty (1-F_X (t)) \, dt$ for every nonnegative random variable $X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841) to see why.

In the paper, you have the expectation of the random quantity
$t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}} - t_k$ conditioned on 
$t_k < t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}} \le  t_{k + 1},$ 
where $t_k$ and $t_{k+1}$ are non-random numbers.
Since the condition implies that 
$t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}} - t_k > 0,$
the conditional distribution is that of a non-negative variable,
so we can use Equation $(2),$ but we have to write it in terms of the condition
$t_k < t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}} \le  t_{k + 1}$:

$$ E(t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}} - t_k \mid t_k < t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}} \le  t_{k + 1}) = \int_0^\infty P(t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}} - t_k > \tau \mid t_k < t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}} \le  t_{k + 1})\, d\tau. \tag3$$

Now we just need to notice that 
$P(t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}} - t_k > \tau \mid t_k < t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}} \le  t_{k + 1}) = 0$
whenever $\tau > t_{k+1} - t_k,$
so we can change the upper end of the integral from $\infty$ to
$t_{k+1} - t_k$ without changing the value of the integeral.
and that $t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}} - t_k > \tau$ is equivalent to
$\tau < t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}} - t_k.$
Therefore the integral on the right-hand side of Equation $(3)$ 
would be equal to the integral in Expression $(1),$ except for one thing:
in Expression $(1),$ we see $\tau < t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}} - t_k,$
which (as you observed) is not equivalent to 
$t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}} - t_k > \tau.$

It seems easy enough to show that the formula in the paper is wrong.
A single counterexample will suffice. Let $t_k = 0,$ $t_{k+1} = 1,$ and suppose the failure (if there is one in that interval) invariably occurs in the interval $(0,0.01].$
That is, given $0 = t_k < t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}} \le  t_{k + 1} = 1,$
then $0 < t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}} \le  0.01,$
and so the conditional expectation of $t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}}$ cannot be greater than $0.01.$
But $P(\tau > t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}} 
 - t_k \mid t_k < t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}} \le  t_{k + 1}) = 1$
whenever $\tau > 0.01,$ so the value of the integral in $(1)$ is at least 
$\int_{0.01}^1 1\,d\tau = 0.99.$

Comment: $\tau < t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}} - t_k.$ which is not equivalent to, $\tau > t_{f_{\scriptstyle i}} - {t}_{k}$. I dont understand how they are equal. Everything else that you have written is crystal clear.

Comment: Hah, well spotted! That got past me, and apparently also got past the reviewers. I don't know what the final resolution is; the error seems to carry forward for at least a few lines of equations.

Answer (score 0):

The expectation can also be written as an integral. The two integrals can be transformed into each other by [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts).

Comment: Are you saying that expectation is the integral of probability?

Comment: @genesis: I'm not sure what you mean by that sweeping statement. I said something more specific than that. Have you actually tried writing the expectation as an integral and transforming the two integrals into each other using integration by parts? (I'm assuming that you know how to write the expectation of a continuous random variable as an integral.)