# Proving $E(X^p)=\int_0^\infty px^{p-1}P(X>x)dx$

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $X$ be a positive random variable on the $(\Omega,\mathscr{A},P)$. Show that if $X\in L_p$ for $1<p<\infty$.
>   Prove $E(X^p)=\int_{0}^{\infty}px^{p-1}P(X>x)dx$

I have been thinking about this question but it does not come to my mind how should I go from $E(X^p)=\int |X|^p dP$ into a Riemann integral. I understand that $\frac{d(x^p)}{dx}=px^{p-1}$ however I cannot see how the Riemann integral appears.
$\int\mathbb{1}_{X>x}dP=P(X>x)$.

**Question:**

How should I solve this question?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cavalieri principle.

Comment: See [Explain why $E(X) = \int_0^\infty (1-F_X (t)) \, dt$ for every nonnegative random variable $X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841/explain-why-ex-int-0-infty-1-f-x-t-dt-for-every-nonnegative-randonoredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write
$$\mathbb{E}[X^p] = \int_\Omega X(\omega)^p \mathbb{P}(d \omega)$$
The trick is to then write $x^p = \int_0^x ps^{p-1} ds$ to get that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X^p]  &= \int_\Omega \int_0^{X(\omega)} ps^{p-1} ds \mathbb{P}(d \omega)
\\& = \int_0^\infty \int_\Omega 1_{X(\omega) > s} ps^{p-1} \mathbb{P}(d \omega) ds
\\& = \int_0^\infty ps^{p-1} \mathbb{P}(X>s) ds
\end{align}
where I was able to swap the integrals around using Fubini's theorem since $X$ is non-negative.