# Show that $\int_{-\infty}^{a}F(x)dx = \int_{a}^{\infty}[1-F(x)]dx$ if and only if $a = \mu$.

Tags: probability

Let X be a random variable with mean $\mu$ and continuous cumulative distribution function $F$. Show that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{a}F(x)dx = \int_{a}^{\infty}[1-F(x)]dx$$

if and only if $a = \mu$.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841/explain-why-ex-int-0-infty-1-f-x-t-dt-for-every-nonnegative-rando) seems related, and I believe that changing the order of integration is involved but I haven't been able to work out the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integrate by parts.
\begin{equation*}
  \int_{-\infty}^{a}x f(x) dx =a F(a)-\int_{-\infty}^{a}F(x)dx
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
  \int_{a}^{\infty}x f(x) dx=a(1-F(a))+\int_{a}^{\infty}(1-F(x))dx
\end{equation*}
Therefore
\begin{equation*}
  \mu =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x f(x) dx= a-\int_{-\infty}^{a}F(x)dx+\int_{a}^{\infty}(1-F(x))dx
\end{equation*}

Comment: Not every distribution with a continuous CDF has a density, see e.g. the Cantor distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other question, you can write

$$\begin{align*}
E[X] &= E[X \cdot I\{X > 0\}] + E[X \cdot I\{X \le 0\}] \\
&= E\Big[\int_0^\infty I\{X > t\} \, dt\Big] - E\Big[\int_{-\infty}^0 I\{X \le t\}\Big] \\
&= \int_0^\infty 1 - E[I\{X \le t\}] \, dt - \int_{-\infty}^0 E[I\{X \le t\}] \, dt \\
&= \int_0^\infty 1 - F(t) \, dt - \int_{-\infty}^0 F(t) \, dt \\
&= \int_0^a 1 - F(t) \, dt + \int_a^\infty 1 - F(t) \, dt - \int_{-\infty}^a F(t) \, dt - \int_a^0 F(t) \, dt \\
&= a + \int_a^\infty 1 - F(t) \, dt - \int_{-\infty}^a F(t) \, dt\,.
\end{align*}$$