# Expectation formula and cdf

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

Let $X$ be a real-valued random variable with the cdf $F_X$. I need to show that
$$
E(X)=\int_0^\infty (1-F_X(x))dx-\int_{-\infty}^0 F_X(x)dx
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

You can write $X=X^+-X^-$ where $X^+=\max(0,X)$ and $X^-=\max(0,-X)$.

Then $X^+$ and $X^-$ are both nonnegative random variables and it is well known that for any nonnegative random variable $Y$ we have $\mathbb EY=\int 1-F_Y(y)dy$.

For a proof of that see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/172841/75923) for instance.