# Formula for the expectation $E|X|=\int_{0}^{\infty} P[|X|>t] dt$

Tags: probability, expected-value

I wonder why $E|X|=\int_{0}^{\infty} P[|X|>t] dt$.
X is a positive random variable with density $f_X$

**What I have done so far**
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} P[|X|>t] dt = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{t}^{\infty} f_X (y) dy dt =  \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{y} f_X (y) dt dy $$

From there, I am not sure how to proceed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $|X|$ is  a nonnegative random variable and so your question is a duplicate of [Explain why $E(X) = \int_0^\infty (1-F_X (t)) \, dt$ for every nonnegative random variable $X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841/explain-why-ex-int-0-infty-1-f-x-t-dt-for-every-nonnegative-rando)

Comment: And you already come to the point that you can integrate the inner integral.