# Finding second moment given $P(X>t)$

Tags: variance, distribution-tails

I know that for nonnegative continuous R.V, $E[X]=\int_0^\infty P(X>t)dt$. Is there a formula for $E[X^2]$ when we only have $P(X>t)$?

Comment: Could this work $E[X^2] = \int P(X^2 > t)dt = \int P(X > \sqrt{t}) + P(X< -\sqrt{t})dt$

Comment: @nls would $P(X<-\sqrt t)=0$

Comment: This comment is to link this post as one of the [(abstract) duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29382/356647) to the current choice of [mother post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841). It is generalized to any $E[X^p]$ in the answer post there.

Answer (score 1):

Using integration by parts one may show: $$EX^2=\int_0^{\infty}2xP(X>x)dx$$

the tails should go to zero fast enough though :-)

---

Addendum

\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty}2xP(X>x)dx&=\int_0^{\infty}2x\left(1-F(x)\right)dx\\
&=x^2\left(1-F(x)\right)|_0^{\infty}+\int_0^{\infty}x^2f(x)dx
\end{align}
Note now that we need $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2(1-F(x))=0$, i.e. the tails should vanish faster than $x^2$.

Comment: care to elaborate. I don't quite get it

Comment: I understand now what you mean. Nonetheless I would like you to explain why I get a contradiction when I use $P(X\le x) $as the derivative instead of $P(X>x)$

Comment: just added more details. Just let the community know if this is not helping :-)

Comment: I understand that derivation as it has been showed to me in an actuarial course. Could you tell me why this does not work $\int_0^\infty x^2f(x)dx=[x^2F(x)]^\infty_0-2\int^\infty_0xF(x)dx$. This is also done using integration by parts but I get inifity - infinity.

Comment: By the way what about nls's suggestion given in the comments above. Thank you very much.

Comment: Would be great to ask all the "new" questions, as a new question :-) it does attract enough attention from the community and it is not easy to answer them in comments cleanly.