# How to find the variance of x from a given cumulative distribution function when the function contains no variable x?

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, cumulative-distribution-functions

[image]

The way I see people going about it is first differentiating to get the p.d.f, then integrating over the given bounds to get the expected value, then using the formula for variance to find the variance from the expected value. But this c.d.f has no x variable that I can differentiate.

Comment: It's better to [not use image for texts or math expressions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/356647) that is **essential to the question**. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: The jumps at $x = 0, 1, 2, 5$ ought to suggest something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3512545/finding-second-moment-given-pxt/3512563#3512563) we find $$E(X)=\int_0^5(1-F(x)) dx$$ and $$EX^2=2\int_0^5x(1-F(x)) dx$$
from which you can calculate the variance.