# Variance of mixed random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, variance

$X \sim F(x)$

$$F(x)=\begin{cases}0,&x<0\\x^2,&0\leq x<1/2\\x,&1/2\leq x<1\\1,&x>1\end{cases}$$

(not right-continuous)

I want to compute $\operatorname{Var}(X)$.

Is this correct:

$$\mathbb E[X]=\int_0^{1/2}2x^2\,dx+\int_{1/2}^1x\,dx+1/2\cdot \mathbb P(1/2)$$

How can I evaluate $\mathbb P(X=1/2)$? Is it $1/2 -(1/2)^2$?
And how do I evaluate $\mathbb E[X^2]$?

$$Y:=X^2$$

$$F_Y(x)=\mathbb P[Y \leq x]=\mathbb P[X^2 \leq x]=\mathbb P[X \leq \sqrt x]=F(\sqrt x)=\begin{cases}0,&x<0\\x,&0\leq x<1/4\\\sqrt x,&1/4\leq x<1\\1,&x>1\end{cases}$$

$$\mathbb E[X^2]=\int_0^{1/2}2x^3\,dx+\int_{1/2}^1x^2\,dx+1/4\cdot \mathbb P(1/4)$$

$$\mathbb P(X=1/4)=\sqrt{1/4} -1/4?$$

Comment: @phdmba7of12 What do you mean? I used $\mathbb E[X]=\int x \cdot f(x) dx$, so I used the pdf?

Comment: @phdmba7of12 There is no pdf.

Comment: By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841/explain-why-ex-int-0-infty-1-f-x-t-dt-for-every-nonnegative-rando?noredirect=1&lq=1) result, you can use $E(X)=\int_0^\infty (1-F(x))\,dx$ and $E[X^2]=2\int_0^\infty x(1-F(x))\,dx$ as $X$ is non-negative.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I thought about using that result as well but I didn't know if I can use this for mixed random variables, or for cdf that are not continuous like this one  (at $x=1/2$)

Comment: @user756349 It holds for *any* non-negative random variable $X$.

Comment: What you suggest is correct, but then there's the problem of how to prove it's correct based on basic definitions. Maybe I'll post on that later. $\qquad$

Comment: why "(not right-continuous)"???!!!

Answer (score 2):

the variance should be $$\operatorname{Var}(X)=\mathbb E[(X-\mathbb E[X])^2] = \mathbb E[X^2]-\mathbb E[X]^2$$ 
$$\mathbb E[g(x)]=\int g(x) f(x) \, dx$$
where $f(x)$ is the probability distribution function (pdf)
$$f(x)=\frac{dF(x)}{dx}=\frac{1}{4}\delta(x-\frac{1}{2})+\begin{cases}0,&x<0\\2x,&0\leq x<1/2\\1,&1/2\leq x<1\\0,&x>1\end{cases}$$
where $\delta (x)$ is the Dirac delta function
$$\mathbb E[X]=\int_0^{1/2}2x^2 dx+\int_{1/2}^1x \, dx+\frac{1}{4}\int \delta(x-\frac{1}{2})x \, dx$$
$$=\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3+\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)+\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{7}{12}$$

$$\mathbb E[X^2]=\int_0^{1/2}2x^3\ dx+\int_{1/2}^1x^2\ dx+ \frac{1}{4}\int \delta(x-\frac{1}{2})x^2dx$$
$$=\frac{2}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4+\frac{1}{3}\left(1-\frac{1}{8}\right)+\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)=\frac{296}{768}$$
$$\mathbb E[X^2]-\mathbb E[X]^2 = 296/768-49/144 = 13/288$$

Answer (score 0):

Your expression for $\ \mathbb{E}\left[X\right]\ $ is correct if $\ \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\ $ is taken to mean the same thing as $\ \mathbb{P}\left(X=\frac{1}{2}\right)\ $. And yes, the value of $\ \mathbb{P}\left(X=\frac{1}{2}\right)\ $ is the size of the jump in $\ F\ $ at $\ x=\frac{1}{2}\ $:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(X=\frac{1}{2}\right)=F \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\lim_{x\rightarrow\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^-}F(x)= \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\ .
$$
There's a problem, however with your formula for $\ \mathbb{E}\left[X^{\color{red}2}\right]\ $ (even apart from the typo flagged by the red superscript in the preceding expression, which is missing from the expression on the left side of your equation).  You appear to have used something like the identity
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[X^2\right]&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2dF(x)\\
&=\int_0^\frac{1}{2}x^2F'(x)dx +\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\mathbb{P}\left(X=\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
&\hspace{1.5em}+ \int_ \frac{1}{2}^0x^2F'(x)dx\\
&= \int_0^\frac{1}{2}2x^3dx+ \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\mathbb{P}\left(X=\frac{1}{2}\right)+\int_\frac{1}{2}^1x^2dx\ ,
\end{align}
which would have been correct, but in place of $\ \mathbb{P}\left(X=\frac{1}{2}\right)\ $ you have $\ \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\ $.  Was this another typo?

Also, your derivation of the distribution of $\ Y=X^2\ $ is a little puzzling. While the derivation is correct, and this distribution *could* have been used to compute $\ \mathbb{E}\left[Y\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[X^2\right]\ $, you haven't actually made any use of it.

Comment: Yes, those were typos. Did you mess up the upper limit of the 2nd integral at the evaluation of $\mathbb E[X^2]$? It should be $\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1$ instead of $\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^0$?

And I thought that I need the distribution of $Y$ to find out that the discontinuity is at $1/4$

Comment: Yes, the $\ 0\ $ at the upper limit of that integral was a typo.  When evaluating $\ \mathbb{E}\left(X^2\right)\ $ by integrating $\ x^2\ $ with respect to the distribution $\ F\ $ of $\ X\ $, it's the discontinuity of $\ F\ $ you need to use, not that of $\ F_Y\ $.  You already know that the former occurs at $\ x=\frac{1}{2}\ $, and the term this gives you in the integration is the square of $\ x\ $ at that point (namely $\ \frac{1}{4}\ $) times the size of the jump in $\ F\ $ there (also equal to $\ \frac{1}{4}\ $).

Comment: You would only need to use the discontinuity in $\ F_Y\ $ at $\ y=\frac{1}{4}\ $ if you were to evaluate $\ \mathbb{E}\left(X^2\right)= \mathbb{E}(Y)\ $ by integrating $\ y\ $ with respect to the distribution $\ F_Y\ $ of $\ Y\ $.