# Expectation of the sum of two random variables whose probabilities are individualy bounded

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

I encountered the following problem:

I have two random variables $A$ and $B$. I know only that $$P(|A|>\epsilon)\leq a(\epsilon)$$ and $$P(|B|>\epsilon)\leq b(\epsilon)$$ 
where $a$ and $b$ are known functions dependending on $\epsilon$.

Can I say something about the expectation of $E[A+B]$? 
Also an inequality involving $E[A+B]$ would be helpful!

Comment: Thank you, but I mean in terms of $a$ and $b$

Comment: You can say that $E[|A+B|] \leq E[|A|+|B|]=E[|A|]+E[|B|]=\int a(x)dx+\int b(x)dx.$ See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841/explain-why-ex-int-0-infty-1-f-x-t-dt-for-every-nonnegative-rando) for the last equality.

Comment: Sorry, above the last equality should in fact be an inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that  $|A+B| > 2 \epsilon$ implies $|A| > \epsilon$ or $|B| > \epsilon$, so 
$P(|A+B| > 2 \epsilon) \le a(\epsilon) + b(\epsilon)$.  This in turn implies
$$E|A+B| = \int_0^\infty P(|A+B| > x) \; dx \le \int_0^\infty (a(x/2) + b(x/2))\; dx$$

Comment: Can it be generalized to find $E|A+B|^p$, $p>1$?