# Expectation of the power of sum of two random variables whose probabilities are individualy bounded

Tags: probability, expected-value

I have been inspired by this question: [Expectation of the sum of two random variables whose probabilities are individualy bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3603309/expectation-of-the-sum-of-two-random-variables-whose-probabilities-are-individua)
I am wondering if solution can be generalized for 
$$
E(A+B)^p,
$$
where $p>1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply almost exactly the same procedure by just using that
$$ \mathbb{P}(|A+B|^p>x) \; = \; \mathbb{P}(|A+B|>x^{1/p})$$
since the $p$-th root is increasing on $[0,\infty)$.