# Prove the following hope equality

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$X$ is a non negative ramdom variable, prove that $EX = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(X>t)dt$.

Well I don't know how to start to prove this, I have a clue that says to me that is: write $P(X>t)$ as the integral of the index function and use the Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Integration by parts?

Comment: Please search the site. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/172841/321264 and its countless linked threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you can use Fubini's theorem to write

$$
\int_0^\infty P(X>t)dt = \int_0^\infty E [\mathbb 1_{\{X>t\}}]dt
= E \left[\int_0^\infty \mathbb 1_{\{X>t\}}dt \right]
= E \left[X \right].
$$

The use of Fubini is justified by the fact that the integrand is non-negative.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the definition and integrate it by parts

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_0^{\infty} [1-F_X(x)]dx= 0 +\int_0^{\infty} xf(x)dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Crucial and simple observation is $X = \int_0^X ds$ if $X$ is non-negative.

Then due to Fubini (non negative):

$$ \mathbb E[X] = \mathbb E[\int_0^X  ds] = \mathbb E[\int_0^\infty 1_{\{X>s\}}ds] = \int_0^\infty \mathbb E[1_{\{X>s\}}]ds = \int_0^\infty \mathbb P(X>s)ds$$