# Finding expectation of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

Let $X$ be a random variable whose distribution function is given by
$$
\mathrm{F}\left(x\right) =
\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
{\displaystyle 0} & \mbox{if} & {\displaystyle x < 2}
\\[1mm]
{\displaystyle{1 \over 3}\,x} & \mbox{if} &
{\displaystyle 2 \leq x \leq 3}
\\[1mm]
{\displaystyle 1} & \mbox{if} & {\displaystyle x > 3}
\end{array}\right.
$$
Then find $E\left(X\right)$ and $E\left(X^{2}\right)$.

Given random variable is neither discrete nor continuous. Then by Jordan decomposition theorem first we have to write $X$ as a sum of a step function and a continuous function.  But how should I do
that ?.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/172857/321264.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Stieltjes integral formula.

$E(X^k)=\int_R x^kdF(x)=\frac{2}{3}2^k+\int_2^3 \frac{x^k}{3}dx$